# Applying a ++ operator to a java int array to store occurrences of characters in a pattern

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to understand this line of code, which is intended to store occurrences of characters in a string.

```
hash_str[str.charAt(i)]++
```

If I add this to a loop and define the `hash_str` array and `str` string as follows and just print the line, I get the following `output`.

```
String str = "this is a test string";
int len1 = str.length();
int hash_str[] = new int[256];

for (int i = 0; i < len1; i++) {
    System.out.println(hash_str[str.charAt(i)]++);
}

**output**
0
0
0
0
0
1
1
1
0
2
1
0
2
2
3
3
3
0
2
0
0
```

However, if I do the following and then try to print the results stored in the array itself, the output is all zeroes. Why are the occurrences not stored?

```
String str = "this is a test string";
int len1 = str.length();
int hash_str[] = new int[256];

for (int i = 0; i < len1; i++) {
    hash_str[str.charAt(i)]++;
}
for (int i = 0; i < len1; i++) {
    System.out.println(hash_str[i]);
}

**output**
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

Comment: That line **counts** occurrences in a string, not stores them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just break it down one part at a time.

```
hash_str[str.charAt(i)]++
```

`hash_str[]` is an array of ints.  Btw, `new int[256]` is wrong because the maximum value of a `char` is 65355.

`str.charAt(i)` is the value of the character at some the ith position in the string.  This loop just accesses the characters in the string sequentially one at a time.

`hash_str[str.charAt(i)]` Access the element of the array at a position equal to the character's value.  If the first letter is 'T' ("This is a string.") the first access will be at array position 84, the ascii/char value of 'T'.

And the `++` at the end just increases the value previous stored at that position.  So the value at `hash_str[84]` just gets incremented by one.

Part of the problem is I think you're not seeing the steps.  Try to break up that long line into smaller parts:

```
String str = "This is a test string";
int len1 = str.length();
int hash_str[] = new int[256];

for (int i = 0; i < len1; i++) {
    int index = str.charAt(i);
    hash_str[index]++;
    System.out.println( "index - " + index ", val " + hash_str[index] );
}

for( int x = ' '; x < '~'; x++ ) {
   System.out.println( x + ": " + ((char)x) + " -- " + hash_str[x] );
}
```

That last bit is tested, it appears to run OK.

Comment: Uhm, 84 is for capital T, but in the string there's lowercase t, hence index is 116.

Comment: Yeah I switched it on purpose: capital letters have different codes.  Important to notice that.

Answer (score 6):

you must print all until 256 to see the occurrence

```
for (int i = 0; i < hash_str.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(hash_str[i]);
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate that a bit? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: The problem is that there are 256 array elements and you are only printing the first 20 or 30 or so.  Here's a question for you: what do  you think will happen if the input string is *longer* than 256 characters?

Answer (score 2):

Let's break this line

```
hash_str[str.charAt(i)]++
```

into fragments. So first we obtain current value of `i` and at the beginning it's 0. Then we call `str.charAt(0)` what gives us the character of String `str` at index 0, which is letter `t`. Then we use this letter `'t'` (of value dec 116) as index in the table `hash_str`, so we "position" a virtual cursor in the table at element of index 116. Then we execute postincrementation (i.e. ++ right operator), which increases the value in the table under the index 116 by 1. And then we get next char from the String and increase value under corresponding index in the table and so on. Finally the table contains histogram of occurrences of characters from range 0..255. (BTW if you place in the string a character outside this code range, you'll get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.